# Retrain Inception Model Error in Android

Tags: android, tensorflow, pre-trained-model

I am following [Tensorflow for poet](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#0) instruction for retrain model. I have successfully create retrained_graph.pb and retrained_labels.txt. While I use imagenet_comp_graph_label_strings.txt and tensorflow_inception_graph.pb then application run without any error. But use my created file then I get error that:

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Op BatchNormWithGlobalNormalization is not available in GraphDef version 21. It has been removed in version 9. Use tf.nn.batch_normalization(). at org.tensorflow.Graph.importGraphDef(Native Method) at org.tensorflow.Graph.importGraphDef(Graph.java:118) at org.tensorflow.Graph.importGraphDef(Graph.java:102) at org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface.load(TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java:402) at org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface.initializeTensorFlow(TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java:91) at org.tensorflow.demo.TensorFlowImageClass

I Also try to retrain model from scratch followed [TensorFlow guides](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining) but I get same error.
I also try to strip graph and change in ClassifierActivity. But still I get same error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using two incompatible versions of TensorFlow, one to train the first model and a different older one is getting called from java.

How are you using the created files? Can you rebuild the programs which do that to use newer versions of tf?

Comment: I am using latest version of tenserflow for run application.For train model I use link that post in question.I put created file in asset folder and add libtensorflow_demo.so in libs folder.In this way I able to run tensorflow model but not by my created model.

Comment: The version on the android runtime is definitely older than 1.0, because of the error message.